# Is it safe to distribute tools.jar along with a Java application bundle?

Tags: jvm, java, sun, tools.jar

Although `tools.jar` is not a component in JRE, but it comes with all major implementations of JDK such as Oracle JDK and OpenJDK.

Not being standard component of JRE means that when I distribute a Java application which uses `tools.jar`, I have to distribute it along with the application bundle OR include it in classpath.

My questions are:

- Does tools.jar contain platform-dependent components that prevent it from being distributed across different platforms (Windows/Linux/OSX)?
- We already know that Oracle JDK does not allow distribution of `tools.jar`, but what about OpenJDK, can we distribute tools.jar from OpenJDK to avoid licensing issue?
- If tools.jar cannot be distributed along with a Java application, is there a platform-independent way to determine its location, so that it can be put into classpath?

Comment: I don't think your second question about the license is on-topic for SO - not enough lawyers here, so any response can only lead to an unwanted discussion.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Short Answer:** You **cannot** redistribute just `tools.jar` either from Oracle JDK or from OpenJDK without redistributing whole bundle.

**Detailed Answer below:**

After reading few articles over internet, below are my findings about your questions:

> Does tools.jar contain platform-dependent components that prevent it
>   from being distributed across different platforms (Windows/Linux/OSX)?

There is no standard dependency defined for `tools.jar`. I have written a sample program which runs perfectly on the Unix and Windows machines. I have copied `tools.jar` from a Windows machine to a Unix machine. Everything works fine.

> We already know that Oracle JDK does not allow distribution of
>   tools.jar, but what about OpenJDK, can we distribute tools.jar from
>   OpenJDK to avoid licensing issue?

- In order to distribute `tools.jar`, you must redistribute the **entire** Oracle JDK, OR the entire JRE with just "The javac bytecode compiler" which includes `tools.jar`; that redistribution is allowed to be "bundled" with your app.
- Redistributed JDK or JRE must be "complete and unmodified" (minus a couple sections about things you can add and/or subtract).
- You can never redistribute beta versions.
- You comply with the other general terms covered in the redistribution section of the [license](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/readme-142177.html#redistribution).

**Source:** [Can we redistribute Oracle tools.jar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6755414/can-we-redistribute-oracle-tools-jar)
**Oracle JDK License:** http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/readme-142177.html#redistribution

> If tools.jar cannot be distributed along with a Java application, is
>   there a platform-independent way to determine its location, so that it
>   can be put into classpath?

[OpenJDK](http://openjdk.java.net/legal/gplv2+ce.html) carries GNU General Public License, version 2, with the Classpath Exception. A licensee of GPL v2-licensed software can:

- copy and distribute the program’s unmodified source code (Section 1)
- modify the program’s source code and distribute the modified source (Section 2)
- distribute compiled versions of the program, both modified and unmodified (Section 3) provided that:

  - all distributed copies (modified or not) carry a copyright notice and exclusion of warranty (Section 1 and 2)
  - all modified copies are distributed under the GPL v2 (Section 2)
  - all compiled versions of the program are accompanied by the relevant source code, or a viable offer to make the relevant source code available (Section 3)

You can get more details of GPL v2 at [The GNU General Public License v2 - An Overview](http://oss-watch.ac.uk/resources/gpl)

---

**UPDATE:** Locate & add `tools.jar` into classpath.

If the end user is running the application using JDK, you will get the desired `tools.jar` automatically. If not, then you need to suggest the user to install `JDK`.

To check this through the program, you can make use of Eclipse JDT JARs. Below code shows how to locate the absolute path of the current JDK/JRE in JVM, and also to add the JAR to `classpath`.

```
IVMInstall jre = JavaRuntime.getDefaultVMInstall();         
File jdkHome = jre.getInstallLocation();
IPath toolsPath = new Path(jdkHome.getAbsolutePath())
       .append("lib")
       .append("tools.jar");
IRuntimeClasspathEntry toolsEntry =
   JavaRuntime.newArchiveRuntimeClasspathEntry(toolsPath);
toolsEntry.setClasspathProperty(IRuntimeClasspathEntry.USER_CLASSES);
```

Source: [Launching Java Applications Programmatically](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Java-launch/launching-java.html)

You can check if here if tools.jar is not present then show the message, else add it to the classpath programatically.

Shishir

Comment: Thanks very much, could you please elaborate more on how to determine the location of tools.jar on windows and linux, so that it may be included in classpath?

Comment: Updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: You can very much redistribute tools.jar without the rest. This is a separate repo and distro: see my answer herehttp://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/4569/can-we-redistribute-openjdk-tools-jar/4583#4583

Answer (score 3):

Wouldn't it be easier just to require that a JDK be installed and $JAVA_HOME be set?  It seems rather dangerous to package tools.jar with your app.  It would then be the user's responsibility to get $JAVA_HOME on the $PATH however they choose to do it.