# run spring boot with java -jar with tools.jar as dependency

Tags: java, spring, maven, jar, spring-boot

I am trying to run a springboot app that needs tools.jar as a dependency, I runned "mvn package spring-boot:run" and everything goes ok, but after packaging with "mvn package spring-boot:repackage" and running with java -jar the generated boot.jar the throws the following error

```
java -jar "site-0.1.0-spring-boot.jar" 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/tools/attach/AttachNotSupportedException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.tools.attach.AttachNotSupportedException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.doLoadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:178)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 5 more
```

JAVA_HOME is pointing to JDK as it should, and this is my pom

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <activejpa.version>0.2.5-SNAPSHOT</activejpa.version>
    <embedded.mongo.version>1.50.3</embedded.mongo.version>
</properties>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>19.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.activejpa</groupId>
        <artifactId>activejpa-core</artifactId>
        <version>${activejpa.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-java8</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- MongoDB -->
    <!-- dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId> 
        </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId> <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId> 
        <version>${embedded.mongo.version}</version> </dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb.morphia</groupId>
        <artifactId>morphia</artifactId>
        <!-- See https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/releases for the latest version -->
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- THYMELEAF -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
        <version>${thymeleaf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring3</artifactId>
        <version>${thymeleaf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>activejpa-mvn-repo</id>
        <url>https://raw.github.com/juanignacionogueira/activejpa/mvn-repo/snapshots/</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>

    <repository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <classifier>spring-boot</classifier>
                        <mainClass>com.rinlit.RinconLiterarioApplication</mainClass>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Any Idea of how should I run it without mvn? what am I doing bad?

Comment: "that needs tools.jar as a dependency". I don't see that dependency in your pom.

Comment: No, I have added in another try with the maven definition but is not working anyway and I have removed it. I supose that it should be there if you run it with JDK insted of JRE, and it works ok with spring boot run, so the dependency is there in that case, but after package is not...

Comment: system scoped dependencies are not added to the fat jar. You don't want to repackage "tools.jar" in your Spring Boot app, that feels really wrong. The funny part is that [I am actually working on support system-scope dependencies _right now_](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2224)!

Comment: what you mean is that I shouldnt be needing that dependency? I am working with activejpa (implementation of active record pattern) and it appends an agent to the vm, till the part I have seen that is done through that jar, that's the reason I need it...

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22305686/is-it-safe-to-distribute-tools-jar-along-with-a-java-application-bundle). In the meantime, I've implemented inclusion of system scoped dependencies in boot. This will be available in 1.4.0.RC1 (next release).

Comment: Thanks so much!! You helped me to understand de problem and with the solution! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

System scope dependencies are not added in the repackaged jar (e.g. 'fat' jar). That is why your app works fine in development (with the "local" classpath) and does not when started as a separate package.

The [upcoming Spring Boot `1.4.0.RC1` release will support this feature](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2224): you'll be able to set  `includeSystemScope` in your Maven plugin configuration and any system scoped dependencies will be included. Note that repackaging `tools.jar` is probably a smell, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22305686/is-it-safe-to-distribute-tools-jar-along-with-a-java-application-bundle)