# Can I upload tools.jar on Maven Central?

Tags: java, maven, jdi

My application uses the JDI debugger classes, which are in `tools.jar`. I want the application to be packaged as standalone using `Maven` (ie creating a `foo-with-dependencies.jar`).

However, `tools.jar` is not on Maven Central.

Popular [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080437/jdk-tools-jar-as-maven-dependency) on Stack Overflow is not valid, since the `<scope>system</scope>` prevents `tools.jar` to be put in `foo-with-dependencies.jar`.

Are there any licensing reasons for the absence of tools.jar on Maven central? Can I upload `tools.jar` on `Maven Central`?

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-central-repository-upload.html

Comment: see also http://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/4569/can-we-redistribute-openjdk-tools-jar

Answer (score 1):

> Only releases can be uploaded to the central repository, that means files that won't change and that only depend on other files already released and available in the repository.
>
> There are some requirements for the minimal information in the POMs that are in the central repository. The updated list of requirements can be found [here](http://central.sonatype.org/pages/requirements.html).

Well, your case is on top of [guide central repository upload](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-central-repository-upload.html). No. It's against basic requirements.

You can upload `tools.jar` to Maven Central if you're the owner or the license let's you do that.

According to [Maven Apache](https://maven.apache.org/general.html#tools-jar-dependency) you can add `tools.jar` to the `pom.xml` in a following way:

```
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>default-tools.jar</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>java.vendor</name>
          <value>Sun Microsystems Inc.</value>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
          <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
          <version>1.4.2</version>
          <scope>system</scope>
          <systemPath>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
```

This still means, that the `tools.jar` isn't available in Maven Central and it looks like it'll never be there.

Comment: The main reason is mostly the Oracle JDK license; you're allowed to distribute a runtime or JDK, separately distributing a component like the tools.jar is prohibited. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22305686/is-it-safe-to-distribute-tools-jar-along-with-a-java-application-bundle