# ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler() retuns null in Eclipse RCP

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I am writing an eclipse plugin and also an RCP application. I have a requirement where I need to compile some java code and I am able to do that using ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler() method and this post http://www.javablogging.com/dynamic-in-memory-compilation/. But the problem is I need to have the JDK in my build path for this to work otherwise it returns null. I can do so in development time, but I am not sure if all the users will have it. So How do I reference JRE and make it work for end users who have only JRE installed?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include tools.jar from jdk/lib to your project dependencies

Comment: Is it legal to add that as part of the plugin? and distribute it?

Comment: Maybe it's not. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6755414/can-we-redistribute-oracle-tools-jar.

Comment: So are there any other alternatives for JavaCompiler that we can use that does not jdk requirement?

Comment: Theoretically, ToolProvider is looking for providers on the classpath using java.util.ServiceLoader mechanism. So if we there is a free implementation of JavaCompiler we can add it instead of tools.jar

Comment: So Can I use the Eclipse Java compiler instead for it? I do not know how to reference it for my plugin though?