# What license is used for JDK/Java EE libraries like activation.jar, servlet.jar or tools.jar?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, licensing

I've been trying to find information on which license is used for files like `activation.jar`, `servlet.jar` or `tools.jar`. These files are bundled with the JDK or an app server.

Oracle's web site is hard to navigate, and I have not been successful finding a clear statement under which conditions I can redistribute these files.

I've found references to old "Sun Binary Licenses", but I guess these have changed when Oracle acquired the whole Java platform.

Can someone point me to a reference that shows which license is used for these files?

*Update*: This question is similar with regards to the JDK files: [Can we redistribute Oracle tools.jar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6755414/can-we-redistribute-oracle-tools-jar?rq=1)

Still looking for an answer for `servlet.jar`.

*Update 2*: This is the current license for Java SE: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/terms/license/index.html - "Oracle Binary Code License"

*Update 3*: The `activation.jar` can be downloaded as the "JavaBeans Activation Framework" here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/jaf11-139815.html - the zip archive contains a file called `LICENSE.txt`, which can be seen e.g. here: http://www.visokio.com/kb/3rdpartylicenses#jaf

Comment: May I ask as to why do you need to know what license Oracle uses?

Comment: You can't re-distribute the tools.jar as it is part of a licensed product, nor would you want it, it must match the version of the JRE installed.

Comment: I'm creating an overview of the (open source) licenses used for a commercial product through its libraries, and I would like to fill the gaps.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Can you point me to a reference explaining that?

Comment: Its in the license agreement you agreed to when you installed the JDK.

Comment: @nwinkler I am assuming that you downvoted my post. Did you read the license **entirely** (From the [link you provided](http://www.visokio.com/kb/3rdpartylicenses#jaf))? In it, it includes the GNU LESSER GENERAL PUBLIC LICENSE Version 2.1, February 1999, just as I stipulated on my post.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [licensing](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274963/1699210) and finding external resources